# in unity in the scene it works but in the build I cant see the weapon why?

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, rendering

Here is the Main camera[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyntU.png)

and Here is the Weapon camera I made to avoid clipping:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNGsG.png)